# Why doesn't the magnetic field make electrons escape out of the material?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons

If a conducting rod moves within a magnetic field, the electrons within it will move for a short amount of time to create a potential difference. When the current is created within this rod, the rod starts moving. In this case, why isn't the magnetic field moving the electrons inside of the rod, but the whole rod instead? Also, in my textbook, the force which creates ac current inside the rod for a short time is described as the "magnetic force", is this correct? shouldn't it be electric force?

Comment: For your first question, the way I think about it is that a small percentage of electrons *do* move inside the rod, which then causes them to “drag” the heavier protons along with them.  This is true for all states of matter (solid, liquid, gas, plasma).  Since the protons in a solid are in a stable structure of some kind, the *dragging* magnetic force drags the entire structure.  When I say a small percentage, likely only 1 electron for every 10,000 atoms in the rod are actually flowing.

Comment: For 2nd question, electromagnetism is the force.  They are one and the same force.  Typically, you say the “magnetic force” induces an “electric current”.  People don’t typically say “electric force”.  It’s more correct to say the “electromagnetic force”.

Comment: A very very very small percentage of electrons do escape from the rod into the air, but the then positively charged atoms on the rod (protons) quickly snatch the lost electrons off of air molecules to fill in the gaps.